# FileNotFoundError while calling heroku run "otree resetdb"

Tags: python, git, heroku, otree

so I receive a `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory error` and I honestly don't know what to do since the file is certainly there. The error occurs when I try to deploy an oTree experiment with heroku and git after command `heroku run "otree resetdb"`. Operating system is Windows 10.

Full error message:

```
Running otree resetdb on ⬢ otreeexperimentna... up, run.5607 (Free)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/otree_startup/__init__.py", line 227, in do_django_setup
    django.setup()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/experimentMusic/models.py", line 21, in <module>
    class Constants(BaseConstants):
  File "/app/experimentMusic/models.py", line 26, in Constants
    with open('D:\Experiment\oTreeproject\oTreeonlineshop-master\shop\oTree\experimentMusic\products.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as jsonfile:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\Experiment\\oTreeproject\\oTreeonlineshop-master\\shop\\oTree\\experimentMusic\\products.json'
```

I also tried a version of code with normal slashes and with double backslashes and still received the same error. Next I tried to rewrite the path in `models.py` using Path from pathlib as follows:

`from pathlib import Path`

```
with open(Path('D:/Experiment/oTreeproject/oTreeonlineshop-master/shop/oTree/experimentMusic/products.json'), 'r', encoding='utf-8') as jsonfile:
        data=jsonfile.read()
        shoppinglist = json.loads(data)
```

It also didn't work, with similar error message.

What could be the problem? The file products.json is there and is not empty, so I have no clue why it doesn't work. I also tried to run the experiment on my laptop and it works perfectly fine, so I guess the problem is the deployment on heroku. Any advice is welcome, thanks so much!

Best,
Lina

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The solution is to rewrite the path to the `.json` file as relative path (instead of absolute).